# How comprehensions work

Tags: elixir

I am trying to understand, how comprehensions work in elixir. Consider following code snippet.

```
iex> for i <- [:a, :b, :c], j <- [1, 2], do:  {i, j}
[a: 1, a: 2, b: 1, b: 2, c: 1, c: 2]
```

How does it work? It loops from top to bottom, like it picks up first an element from i then loop through all element of j, right?

Comment: This question shows almost no research effort. Downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the order of execution, it's equivalent to two nested loops. However, the nested loops will produce nested lists as a result.

```
for i <- [:a, :b, :c] do
  for j <- [1, 2] do
    {i, j}
  end
end

#=> [[a: 1, a: 2], [b: 1, b: 2], [c: 1, c: 2]]
```

To better replicate the original example we could use `Enum.flat_map/2` for all but the innermost loop, which yields the same result.

```
Enum.flat_map [:a, :b, :c], fn(i) ->
  Enum.map [1, 2], fn(j) ->
    {i, j}
  end
end

#=> [a: 1, a: 2, b: 1, b: 2, c: 1, c: 2]
```